# Standards for commandline options documentation

Tags: documentation, command-line-arguments

I often hack out some Thor, Rake, Bash or even PHP commandline tools. And I want to document the command-line-arguments and variations in a consistent way.

Is there an official, or recommended standard on this documentation?

Like when an option is optional[--foo=bar], or when an option can be one n-values ("yes|no"), etceteras.

I'd rather not come up with my own standard, when there is an official (POSIX?) standard or guide that already lists the do's and don't for documenting tools and applications on CLI's.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what output format you have in mind, but why not use the [man-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) style? It seems a nice fit for commandline tools.